# Run a launchd job after Time Machine backup

Tags: macos, time-machine, launchd

Quite simply, I have a process that's triggered by `launchd` but currently runs once an hour, however really what I would like it to do is run once a Time Machine backup has completed.

Initially I thought I could just set my Time Machine backup (/Volumes/Foo/Backups.backupdb/Haravikk's Mac) as a watch path for launchd, however this seems to trigger much too early. It does seem to trigger again near the end, so I'm currently using a delay and then checking for the existence of a .inprogress backup, but it's not really an ideal solution, and sometimes Time Machine's cleanup stage will trigger the process multiple times.

Is there a more specific path that I could watch that will trigger my process only when Time Machine has finished a backup?

I realise I should perform my checks anyway to be sure, but currently my process is triggering several times per backup, which isn't what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so after setting up a launch agent to log information for a while I've come up with a combined solution.

Quite simply I created a launch-agent that watches the `com.apple.TimeMachine.plist` file for updates like-so:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
 <plist version="1.0">
 <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>org.example.backupd</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>do something</string>
    </array>
    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array>
         <string>/Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine.plist</string>
     </array>
 </dict>
 </plist>
```

This file is updated every time Time Machine performs a backup, and runs towards the end (during the cleaning up/finishing stage I believe). With this in mind it is possible to invoke a script with the above watch path that checks to see if `backupd` is still running; if it is then the script sleeps for a minute and checks again, repeating until `backupd` has finished, before proceeding with whatever it needs to do.

This now allows post-backup actions to be triggered such as performing secondary backups (in my case via `rsync` to a NAS), checking the size of the last backup and other handy things.

Anyway, this solution seems to be the best way to do it, as I couldn't find any path to watch that triggers reliably after a backup is complete, but this should run close enough to the end of a backup to be useful.

Comment: This works very well. You do not need to check again a minute later since the plist action will also be triggered at the end of the backup (maybe just wait a few seconds before checking). Also, checking backupd does not work with the latest MacOs versions. However, you can use the undocumented `tmutil status` to check if the backup is still running.

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution is to use the `tmutil` command to manually trigger the backup and follow it up with your process (as part of a shell script that does both these steps).

- First, turn off automatic backups from **System Preferences > Time Machine** or using the command `tmutil disable`
- Use `tmutil startbackup --auto --block` to trigger a backup once every hour (the `--block` option is required to make the execution wait until the backup is finished)
- Follow this with launching your process

See [man tmutil](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/tmutil.8.html) for more information on using `Time Machine` from the command line.

Comment: That would be ideal, and I could maybe make it work, but I was really hoping to be able to make my script a "drop in" addition, leaving Time Machine to function normally (I just don't want to be running at the same time). Is there perhaps a way to look out for `backupd` running and just wait till it finishes before running my script?

Comment: I just tried creating and running a wrapper program for `backupd`, but it runs once every 10 seconds and exits. So monitoring `backupd` is not useful.